# Is it bad to have recursiveness in the code, but not in the serialization?

Tags: java, jpa, recursion

I have this relation between two models: Formulario and Secao.
Formulario has Secao on it, but is transient. Just for code management purposes.
Secao has Formulario, but they have a JPA relation, being @ManyToOne.

To create a "Secao" i have to create one "Formulario" before and then set "Formulario" into the "Secao"(because after being saved in the database, the object has now an id).

The major problem is, now i have some sort of "circular" code. Formulario>Secao>Formulario>Secao (and go on).
As soon i serialize the object it gets messy because of the recursivity. Using @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference managed to fix the serialization problem, but i still have the objects recursive in the memory.

Is it horrible problem?

(This model/relation wasn't done by me and i can't remake it).

```
@Entity(name = "formularios")
@Where(clause = "deletado = 'false'")
public class Formulario extends EntidadeGenerica {

    ....
    @Transient
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Secao> secoes;

    @Transient
    private List<Dependencia> dependencias;
```

```
@Entity(name = "formulario_secoes")
@Where(clause = "deletado = 'false'")
public class Secao extends EntidadeGenerica {

    ....
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean visivelMobile;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "ordem_exibicao")
    private Integer ordemExibicao;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "formulario_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Formulario formulario;
```

```
public Formulario save(@RequestBody Formulario objeto, HttpServletRequest request) {

    try {

        formularioRepository.save(objeto);
        List<Secao> novasSecoes = objeto.getSecoes();

        novasSecoes.stream().map(s -> {
            s.setFormulario(objeto);
            return secaoRepository.save(s);
        });

        return objeto;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
{
    "id": 52,
    "dataUltimaAtualizacao": "2020-03-02",
    "dataCadastro": "2020-02-28",
    "deletado": false,
    "cliente": 1,
    "modulo": 35,
    "nome": "TESTE123",
    "entidadeDestino": "teste123",
    "bancoDadosDestino": "palotina",
    "schemaDestino": "cadastro_tecnico_multifinalitario",
    "ordem": null,
    "formularioPaiId": null,
    "secoes": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "dataUltimaAtualizacao": null,
            "dataCadastro": "2020-02-28",
            "deletado": false,
            "nome": "Dados Morador",
            "visivelMobile": true,
            "ordemExibicao": 1,
            "campos": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "dataUltimaAtualizacao": null,
                    "dataCadastro": "2020-02-28",
                    "deletado": false,
                    "nome": "Nome",
                    "tipo": "TEXTO",
                    "ordemExibicao": 1,
                    "visivelMobile": true,
                    "abrirFormularioFilho": null,
                    "inativo": null,
                    "obrigatorio": true,
                    "secao": null,
                    "atributoDestino": "proprietario",
                    "dependencia": null,
                    "campoOpcaos": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dependencias": null
}
```

[image]

Comment: pay attention to the fact that all the secaos in the stack point to the same collection, hence, it fetches only once. No worries there, its the same as if you were to create two objects that reference each other, and then Trying to get to one via the other in the debugger view.